# Save SerialPort settings in Windows environment

Tags: c#, serial-port, mscomm32

I would like to programmatically set the serial (COM) port settings (baud rate, stop bits etc) in my C# program.When I do something like the following, it does not save the settings in my windows environment. Am I totally on the wrong track?

```
  SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
  string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

  serialPort.PortName = "COM5";
  serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
  serialPort.DataBits = 8;
  serialPort.DtrEnable = true;

  serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
  serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
  if (serialPort.IsOpen) serialPort.Close();
```

Comment: Why would it save the settings? Did you _ask_ it to save the settings? What if you hadn't wanted it to save the settings, and it did it anyway?

Comment: Are you trying to persist your settings between application starts or set them during runtime? Nothing you show here is saving anything.

Comment: Question not obvious, please provide further info by responding to previous comments.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your Project Property's Settings Tab and add the settings for the values you want to persist like this:

[image]

Then access them in your code like this. Saving them when your application closes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SerialPort serialPort; 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialPort = new SerialPort();
        serialPort.PortName = Properties.Settings.Default.PortName;
        serialPort.BaudRate = Properties.Settings.Default.BaudRate;
        serialPort.DataBits = Properties.Settings.Default.DataBits;
        serialPort.DtrEnable = Properties.Settings.Default.DtrEnable;
        serialPort.StopBits = Properties.Settings.Default.StopBits;
        serialPort.Parity = Properties.Settings.Default.Parity;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort.PortName = "COM1";
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.PortName = serialPort.PortName;
        Properties.Settings.Default.BaudRate = serialPort.BaudRate;
        Properties.Settings.Default.DataBits = serialPort.DataBits;
        Properties.Settings.Default.DtrEnable = serialPort.DtrEnable;
        Properties.Settings.Default.StopBits = serialPort.StopBits;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Parity = serialPort.Parity;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); //Saves settings 

    }
}
```